# Hover div another div appear on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating something like this. When I hover the buttons upper content will change but each buttons have different content.

[image]

But I cannot see the content when hovering it :(

Does anybody know how to fix it? or is there any jquery fix?

Thanks in advance

```css
#service-content {
    display: none;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 200px;
 -webkit-animation: flash 1.5s;
 animation: flash 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash {
 0% {
  opacity: .4;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
@keyframes flash {
 0% {
  opacity: .4;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

#home-button-1:hover~#service-content .construction-neuve,
#home-button-2:hover~#service-content .renovation-residentiel,
#home-button-3:hover~#service-content .service-de-plan-et-design,
#home-button-4:hover~#service-content .entrepreneur-commercial,
#home-button-5:hover~#service-content .apres-sinistre,
#home-button-6:hover~#service-content .decontamination-d-amiante
 {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
 -webkit-animation: flash 1.5s;
 animation: flash 1.5s;
}


#slider-buttons .span4 {
    width: 383px;
    float:left;
  height:50px;
}

#slider-buttons .image-content {
 position: relative;
}


#slider-buttons .image-caption {
    background: #000000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #6e6e6e;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 383px;
    font-weight: 600;
}


#slider-buttons .image-caption:hover {
    background: #ba9444 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 383px;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="service-content">
  <div class="construction-neuve">
    content

  </div>

  <div class="renovation-residentiel">
    content

  </div>

  <div class="service-de-plan-et-design">
    content

  </div>

  <div class="entrepreneur-commercial">
    content

  </div>

  <div class="apres-sinistre">
    content

  </div>

  <div class="decontamination-d-amiante">
    content

  </div>
</div>                            

<div id="slider-buttons" class="span12">   



  <div id="construction-neuve" class="span4 m-l00">
    <div class="image-content">
      <img src="images/home-buttons/home-button-1.jpg">
      <div id="home-button-1" class="image-caption">Construction Neuve</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="renovation-residentiel" class="span4 m-l10">
    <div class="image-content">
      <img src="images/home-buttons/home-button-2.jpg">
      <div id="home-button-2" class="image-caption">Rénovation Résidentiel</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="service-de-plan-et-design" class="span4 m-l10">
    <div class="image-content">
      <img src="images/home-buttons/home-button-3.jpg">
      <div id="home-button-3" class="image-caption">Service de plan et design</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="entrepreneur-commercial" class="span4 m-l00">
    <div class="image-content">
      <img src="images/home-buttons/home-button-4.jpg">
      <div id="home-button-4" class="image-caption">Entrepreneur Commercial</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="apres-sinistre" class="span4 m-l10">
    <div class="image-content">
      <img src="images/home-buttons/home-button-5.jpg">
      <div id="home-button-5" class="image-caption">Aprés-Sinistre</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="decontamination-d-amiante" class="span4 m-l10">
    <div class="image-content">
      <img src="images/home-buttons/home-button-6.jpg">
      <div id="home-button-6" class="image-caption">Décontamination d'amiante</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating your problem please?

Comment: I already did :) Click the "Run Code Snippet", but for you, here's the link http://jsfiddle.net/2hy054qq/

Comment: @AlyssaReyes Do you mean that when a button is hovered the content animates using opacity and at the same time all the buttons is pushed down to give space for the content? ... If so, this gets a little bit trickier, as when hover a button, all  the buttons is pushed down which will make the mouse suddenly hover the content instead and so on. Even more trickier will it be when hover button 4-6, as at some point the mouse will hover button 1-3 resp. when they are pushed down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using JQuery.

First, each part that should be hovered must have an `onmouseover` attribute that the first parameter of that should be a unique number. like this:

```
<div onmouseover="run_hover(1);"></div>
<div onmouseover="run_hover(2);"></div>
<div onmouseover="run_hover(3);"></div>
```

and each big part that will be shown should have a unique ID with a number that is the same with the parameter you entered for the div that should be hovered. Like this:

```
<div id="box_for_show">
    <div id="div_1">Content 1</div>
    <div id="div_2">Content 2</div>
    <div id="div_3">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

and this is the JQuery code of that:

```
function run_hover(id) {
    $("#box_for_show div").fadeOut(function(){
        $("#div_"+id).fadeIn();
    });
}
```

Point: `#box_for_show div {display: none;}`

Here is the fiddle that will work for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/h0puq1Ld/4/

Comment: @AlyssaReyes Look at fiddle I added to the answer . It is done :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best [example](http://jsfiddle.net/step/pmpn5g62/) but i hope it helps. You could also use list

```
$('div.image-caption').hover(function(){
    var nums = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#cont-'+nums).css('display','block');
}, function() {
    $('.cont').hide();
});
```